# Difference in data alignment

Tags: c++, alignment

I have the following code:

```
    int byte_align(void * ptr)
    {
        int power = 2, n = 1, result = 0;
        size_t address = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(ptr);
        while(address%power == 0)
        {
            power *=2;
            result = n;
            n++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

When I execute this function (compiled with -O3 on Ubuntu with g++4.6), I get for a double variable on each run different values (4, 5, 7, 8). Why? On another PC with same OS and same compiler I get always 3 as a result.
What are other possible reasons for these results?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you compiling for 32-bit or 64?

Comment: What do you pass as ptr?

Comment: @Pukku: I pass an address to a double, e.g. `double x; func(&x);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure chance.  Depending on the machine, a double must be aligned
on a multiple of 4 or a multiple of 8 (on the common machines).
An alignment of 8 will return 3.  Or more, because anything
which is aligned 16, 32, 64... will also be aligned 8.

You don't say where the pointer comes from, nor the context in
which you are executing (DLL, etc.), so it's hard to say more.
Many systems will place static data, the stack and/or the free
space arena at different addresses each time you run the
program, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

On machines with large address spaces, variables can be located on boundaries larger than 4 bytes (for a 32-bit alignment).

Try your function with these samples:
0x100, 0x101, 0x102, 0x104, 0x108, 0x110

From the information you presented, I can only say that programs may not be located at the same place on every invocation. Therefore, pointers may have different values.

The same is true for data.